# How do I write a CLI app in NodeJS which clears the terminal and then restores it afterwards

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I want to write an interactive command line app which clears the contents of the terminal and then restores it upon exiting, the way that linux commands like `vim` and `less` do. How can I do this with Node.js?

I can clear the terminal using `console.clear()`, but I'm not sure how to restore it to its original state when my app exits.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question...

Turns out you need to use the *alternative buffer*, used by other "full screen" terminal apps like `less` and `vim`. You can do this using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

```js
/** Call this at the start of your program */
const enableAlternativeBuffer = () =>
  process.stdout.write("\u001B[?1049h");

/** Call this before exiting your program */
const disableAlternativeBuffer = () =>
  process.stdout.write("\u001B[?1049l");
```